# Temporarily disable Django cache during Unit Test

Tags: django

Is it possible to run some unit tests with real cache and some with dummy cache ? I'm trying to change cache settings in unit test, but it's not working.

```
class SomeUnitTests(unittest.RollbackTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        settings.CACHES['default'] = {'BACKEND': 'xxx.xxx.DummyCache'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [override_settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings) decorator.

Example:

```
from django.test import override_settings

TEST_CACHE_SETTING = {
   # ...
}

class SomeUnitTests(unittest.RollbackTestCase):

    @override_settings(CACHES=TEST_CACHE_SETTING)
    def test_some(self):
        # Some test here against TEST_CACHE_SETTING

    def test_some_1(self):
        # Another test with the normal cache setup.
```